# google big query - Flush data from buffer (4 days data on buffer)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, gcloud

I Have a python implementation of streaming data to big query, it is similar to the example at docs, in every task I got a "Loaded 1 row into..." but when query the table I only got like 30-35 rows per day(The table is partitioned by day) however I am getting an average of 25k request to data streamed to the table. when looking to the "get" api call it show me like 800 rows ant buffer, but It took 4 days like this and I can't see my data from 4 days ago in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you supplying a deduplication [insertId](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) for each row when you call tabledata.insertAll?  If you're re-using the same insertId for all the inserted rows, you'll observe behaviors similar to this.

Comment: Hi shollyman, I'm using a library to generate a random ID acccording to RFC 4122. https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html

Comment: I´m using versión 4
errors = table.insert_data(rows, row_ids = str(uuid.uuid4()))

Comment: Given this usage, don't supply row_ids.  That said, as written insert_data is using the index of the current row in rows to get a substring from your uuid cast to string, so your insert_id is likely just single character or digit, not a unique uuid per row as you expect.

Comment: Debugging Ids I got strings with 36 chars length, here an example: c55a282e-8b6d-4c78-9056-e148f04daec8
I haven't found 2 similars.

Comment: row_ids should be a list of strings, you're passing the string representation of the uuid4().

Comment: Thanks Shollyman, I passed the Id as a list and It's working perfectly.